# Restoring from Time Machine Backup – Cannot replace Mac HD

Tags: time-machine, restore, sandbox

I'm trying to restore my computer to a previous backup of my Mac HD. However, when I try, I see an error notice telling me that I cannot, since this file is not able to be deleted:

> .PKInstallSandboxManager-SystemSoftware

How do I restore to this backup from last week, considering that I can't delete the above folder, or resultantly, another version of Mac HD ?

What I've done:

Enter Time Machine > scroll through to appropriate backup > hit "restore" button > You can erase volume “Macintosh HD” and replace it with the restored volume or cancel to stop the restore. > receive error notice related to the above.

Comment: Can I suggest you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/304034/edit) your question to describe the steps you're currently taking to restore from Time Machine?

Answer (score 1):

My *assumption* from how your question is worded is that you're trying to recover an entire HD, not just a single file, folder etc.

Instead, to do a full restore of your Mac you need to boot into macOS Recovery and use the **Restore from Time Machine Backup** utility.

You *may* find the following Apple Support resources helpful:

- [About macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201314)
- [How to move your content to a new Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204350)
- [How to use Time Machine to back up or restore your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201250)

Comment: I almost bricked my Mac with your first link

Comment: Really? If there's something unclear on that page you should let Apple know. You'll see at bottom left a **Helpful?** section with Yes | No buttons and clicking on No provides a box for you to provide feedback. Re your question, how are things now? Are you closer to your goal?

Comment: Could you edit the answer, so that I can remove my downvote ? I put my feedback on the first link site and I feel that my -1 was unjustified.

Comment: I've just made an initial edit of my answer, however, if there's something specific you wanted me to add/remove/clarify please let me know. :)